# Merge two Maps with exceptions in java

Tags: java

I would like to merge two Maps that have similar structure:

This is the first Map

```
   {
    "Profile": {
        "Location":
            {
                "City": "Some City",
                "State": "Some State",
                "Country": "USA"
            }
    },
    "TimeLine": {
        "LifeEvents": {
            "EventName": "Got Married",
            "Date": "15-01-2000"
        }
    }
}
```

The second Map is:

```
{
    "Profile": {
        "Office": {
            "City": "New City",
            "State": "New State",
            "Country": "UK"
        }
    },
    "TimeLine": {
        "LifeEvents": {
            "EventName": "Got Engaged",
            "Date": "15-01-1999"
        }
    }
}
```

After merging, I want it to be in the following format:

```
{
    "Profile": {
        "Office": {
            "City": "New City",
            "State": "New State",
            "Country": "UK"
        },
        "Location": {
            "City": "Some City",
            "State": "Some State",
            "Country": "USA"
        }
    },
    "TimeLine": {
        "LifeEvents": [
            {
                "EventName": "Got Engaged",
                "Date": "15-01-1999"
            },
            {
                "EventName": "Got Married",
                "Date": "15-01-2000"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The solution I tried is:

```
private static Map merge(Map original, Map newMap) {

        for (Object key : newMap.keySet()) 
        {
             if (newMap.get(key) instanceof Map && original.get(key) instanceof Map) 
            {
                Map originalChild = (Map) original.get(key);
                Map newChild = (Map) newMap.get(key);
                original.put(key, merge(originalChild, newChild));
            } 
            else if (newMap.get(key) instanceof List && original.get(key) instanceof List)
            {
                List originalChild = (List) original.get(key);
                List newChild = (List) newMap.get(key);
                for (Object each : newChild)
                {
                    if (!originalChild.contains(each))
                    {
                        originalChild.add(each);
                    }
                }
            } else 
            {
                if(!original.containsKey(key)){
                    original.put(key, newMap.get(key));

                }

            }
        }
        return original;
    }
```

Any suggestions how I can modify the above method to handle my requirements?Though the structure of the Map given above is in JSON format, assume that you will get Map as input for merge method. I am using `new Gson().fromJson(map1String, Map.class);` for converting the JSON to a Map.

Comment: Have the first json `{{`, after location, really?

Comment: What is the requirement you are referring to?

Comment: @Aubin sorry its a typo. Fixed it.

Comment: @Izruo its there in third JSON Structure.

Comment: And you posted a solution for that which you want to modify, so I was actually asking: What are the requirements of that modification? - Sorry for being unclear.

Comment: This question is incomplete.  First, you're using raw generics. It should be `Map<K,V>` where `K` and `V` are specified.  I assume `K` is `String`, but we can't guess `V`.  Second, you have a structure that appears to be dynamically nested maps unless `V` is some complex type.  Java is not Javascript or Perl, or Python, where such multi-level dynamic structures are easy. We need a lot more detail to offer a helpful answer.

Comment: @JimGarrison The Map you asking is `Map<String, Object>` You can ask if still you are clueless what I am intended to do

Comment: @Izruo to keep it simple the method I posted above merges two Maps. What I want is to merge two Maps similar to above with this method which should give me a result similar to the third JSON